# Which pictureBox was selected? C#

Tags: c#, events, handler, image

I am working on a piano in C#.  I have encountered a small problem.

I have a piano keyboard which, when pressed, displays the relevant note on the staff.

The notes created are stored in an array of type PictureBox, called picBox.  I have constructed the following event handler, however it is not working.

```
private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            picBox[0].MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pic_Click); //testing for first location
        }

    private void pic_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ClickedTextBox.Text = "I was clicked";
    }
```

I am just testing to see if the first note was clicked.  Why is this not working?

Here is the method which adds the picturebox (containing the note) to the staff (panel3).

```
public void addPictureBox(int x, int y, Image image)
        {
        picBox[cnt] = new PictureBox();

        picBox[cnt].Image = image;
        picBox[cnt].Location = new Point(x, y);
        picBox[cnt].BackColor = Color.Transparent;

        panel3.Controls.Add(picBox[cnt]);
        picBox[cnt].BringToFront();
        cnt++;
    }
```

What is wrong with my event handler please?  Also, what can I do to identify the location in the array of the picturebox clicked?  Thank you

Comment: You subscribe in the `mouseclick` event, subscribe when you create a `picturebox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the first comment, you subscribe to the event in a wrong location.

Also use the `sender` parameter of your event handler to know which picturebox is clicked (it'll contain an instance of the picturebox).