# Refer to Picture Box selected

Tags: c#, resize, picturebox, selected

I am new to C# and want to change the size of some Pictureboxes based on one trackbar Value.
If i write the below code refering to a spesific picturebox (e.g. Picturebox1 instead of PB) it works, but i would like to use one Doubleclick event for all Pictureboxes that i Doubleclick.

The below code gives PB = null.
I get the selected Pictureboxname but how can i refer to this Picturebox?

'''

```
  private void PictureBoxesDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get the selected Picturebox name
            String PictureBoxName = ((PictureBox)sender).Name;

        //This part doesn't work
        PictureBox PB = (PictureBox)this.Controls[PictureBoxName];

        //Resize the Picture box according to the trackBar Value
        PB.Size = new Size(trackBar1.Value, trackBar1.Value);
        PB.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - pictureBox1.Width) / 2;
        PB.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox1.Height) / 2;
     }
```

'''

[Which pictureBox was selected? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678412/which-picturebox-was-selected-c-sharp)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is the common function which I used for the two picture boxes on their double click and it is working fine. Check if you also had a common function for all the picture boxes in the form.

```
private void pictureBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the selected Picturebox name
    String PictureBoxName = ((PictureBox)sender).Name;

    PictureBox PB = (PictureBox)this.Controls[PictureBoxName];

    //Resize the Picture box according to the trackBar Value

    PB.Size = new Size(trackBar1.Value*10, trackBar1.Value*10);
    PB.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - pictureBox1.Width) / 2;
    PB.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox1.Height) / 2;

}
```

[image: Two picture boxes having the same double click event.This is the image before any double click event is fired.]

[image: This is when the double click is fired on both the picture boxes.]

Comment: You are right, i changed the picturebox Backcolor and now the change is visibel. I was looking at the image of the picturebox that doesn't change, even if the picturebox is smaller than the image. Do you have a idea why the image is not changing according to the size of the picturebox?

Comment: Try setting sizemode property of picturebox to zoom. This might help.

Comment: I found it, i have to change picturebox size mode to "stretchimage". Thank you for your Help.